# DRF: Integer expected but received String (using Axios)

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I receive the following error when I try to send an array of id's to the django rest framework:

My payload looks like:

assigned_facilities: 1,2

When I'm using the drf API test page it works and the payload looks like this:
assigned_facilities
:
[1, 2]

So my assumption is that i
I'm missing the brackets and that's why it isn't working? How do I fix that?

```
    const cpBoard = useSelector((state) => state.cpBoard);
    const facilityIds = (cpBoard.cpBoardItems?.map(cpBoardItem => (cpBoardItem.id)));

    function submitFacilities() {

        const facilitydata = new FormData()
        facilitydata.append("assigned_facilities", facilityIds);

        axios.patch(API.leads.update(id), facilitydata, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
            .then(res => {
                setLead(res.data)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false)
            })
    }
```

views.py

```
class LeadUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLeadOwner]
    serializer_class = LeadUpdateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lead.objects.all()
```

serializers.py

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "PrimaryAddress",
            "assigned_facilities",

        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "created_at", "agent", "is_owner")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
 axios.patch(API.leads.update(id), { "assigned_facilities": facilityIds}, {

            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
            .then(res => {
                setLead(res.data)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setSending(false)
            })
    }
```

Sending it instead as FormData just as an Object with a key of assigned_facilities and the value being the facilityIds